# Why is the cross product of two vectors always orthogonal to the input vectors?

Tags: vectors

If $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are two vectors, we get the magnitude of the rotation or moment as $|\mathbf{a}||\mathbf{b}|\sin(\angle ab)$.

Now, we are multiplying that with the unit vector orthogonal to the $\mathbf{ab}$-plane. That's when we get $\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}$ vector.

But my question is, why normal to the $\mathbf{ab}$-plane? Why not in any other direction? Why 90 degree and nothing other than that?

Comment: Do you know the "determinant method" for computing the cross product?

Comment: Yes i do. But the determinant method expects that i × j = k, j × k = i and so on. So why would the cross product vector will be orthogonal to the input vectors?

Comment: @Ron Do you consider the cross products of the basis vectors to be your definition of the cross product?  If so, would you consider it acceptable to show that orthogonality of the cross product to its input vectors as a consequence of that definition?

Comment: If we can show why i x j = k, then we can draw our bigger conclusion why a x b is orthogonal to a and b, right? I guess this is just one way to prove the orthogonality. There must be some other ways too.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few different ways to see this.  If you want to define the cross product in $\mathbb R^3$ in a coordinate-free, geometric manner you *define* $v \times w$ to be equal to the vector with magnitude $\| v \| \cdot \| w\| \sin(\theta)$ (with $\theta$ the angle between $v$ and $w$) pointing in the direction determined by the right-hand rule.  The usual coordinate description is then a consequence of this.

Orthogonality can be deduced from the coordinate description of the cross product via the triple scalar product.  First recall that two non-zero vectors are orthogonal if and only if their inner product is zero.  For $v, w \in \mathbb R^3$,  also recall that $v \cdot (v \times w) = \det (v, v, w)$ and $w \cdot (v \times w) = \det (w, v, w)$.   Here, $(v, v, w)$ and $(w, v, w)$ are taken to be  $3 \times 3$-matrices whose rows are given by the indicated vectors.  Both determinants are $0$ since the matrices have two identical rows and are hence singular.  This shows that both $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal to $v \times w$, so that $v \times w$ is parallel to the normal vector determined by the span of $v$ and $w$.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could think about it another way. Let's say you want to design a product between two vectors $a$ and $b$ with base space $R^3$ with the following properties (we'll use the generic $\times$ for now)

$$
a \times b \text{ is a vector} \\
a \times b = -b \times a \\
a \times (b + c) = a \times b + a \times c \\
(s a) \times b = s (a \times b) \quad  \text{s is a scalar}
$$

Properties 1,3 and 4 immediately suggest the introduction of a linear map 
$T^a(b) \equiv a \times b $.

Clearly, $T^a(b)$ is a vector, and the linearity properties fall (3) and (4) are seen to be satisfied trivially, e.g.

$$
T^a(b + c) = T^a(b) + T^a(c) \equiv a \times b + a\times c
$$

The second property (anti-commutativity) is tricky. It is easier to assert that the linear map $T^a$ must have the form 
$$
T^a =  \epsilon_{ijk} a_j \mathbf{e}_i \otimes \mathbf{e}_k
$$

where $\otimes$ is the tensor product. Does this imply $a \times b = -b \times a$? Well for starters, $a \times a $ must be 0. With our definition, $a \times a $ is

$$
\epsilon_{ijk} a_j \mathbf{e}_i \otimes \mathbf{e}_k \cdot a_m \mathbf{e}_m \\
= \epsilon_{ijk} a_j a_m \delta_{km} \mathbf{e}_i \\
= \epsilon_{ijk} a_j a_k \mathbf{e}_i \\
= 0
$$
The last conclusion follows because $a_j a_k$ will always result in pairs of terms of opposite sign when contracted with the levi-civita symbol.

What about the generalization of this property? Does it include full anti-commutativity?

$$
T^a(b) =  \epsilon_{ijk} a_j \mathbf{e}_i \otimes \mathbf{e}_k \cdot b_m \mathbf{e}_m \\
 = \epsilon_{ijk} a_j b_k \mathbf{e}_i \\
\quad \text { (on simplification using } 
\mathbf{e}_k \cdot \mathbf{e}_m = \delta_{km})
$$

Similarly,
$$
T^b(a) =  \epsilon_{ijk} b_j \mathbf{e}_i \otimes \mathbf{e}_k \cdot a_m \mathbf{e}_m \\
 = \epsilon_{ijk} a_k b_j \mathbf{e}_i \\
 = \epsilon_{ikj} a_j b_k \mathbf{e}_i  \\
 = -T^a(b) 
$$
The last step follows because the indices of epsilon are permuted the other way.

So we have **constructed** a product which has all the properties of a cross product using a linear map.

Now, we can examine the angle between a vector and its cross product using these definitions.

$$ a \cdot (a \times b) \\
 = a \cdot T^a(b) \\
 = a_m \mathbf{e}_m \cdot \epsilon_{ijk} a_j b_k \mathbf{e}_i \\
 = \epsilon_{ijk} a_i a_j b_k \\
 = 0 
$$

Again the last result is easily verified using the properties of the permutation symbol, because it results in pairwise terms of opposite signs like  $\epsilon_{12k} a_1 a_2 b_k + \epsilon_{21k} a_2 a_1 b_k = 0$.

Since $a \cdot (a \times b)$ defined this way is 0, the vector $a \times b$ is perpendicular to $a$. (It will also be perpendicular to b, as is easily verified).